# Is it possible to Nest Partial Designs in Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa

Has anybody ever put one partial design inside of another one?

We are on Sitecore 9.3.0

Comment: I am not really sure what your challenge/goal is but I think these doc pages should help you:
**Snippet** (reusable group of renderings) - https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add,-reuse,-and-edit-a-snippet.html
**Base partial design** ("nested" partial ) - https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/recommendations--structuring-pages.html#UUID-bb67a180-bf67-2c37-6b11-f7df38991c39_section-idm46212287375040_body

Comment: If any of the above don't work for you, let us know what the actual requirement is...